# Why do most HD wallets require choosing either all Segwit or all Legacy but Bitcoin Core can support both simultaneously?

Tags: bitcoin-core, bip32-hd-wallets

Electrum and the mobile wallets I've used can only support one type of address per HD wallet, but Bitcoin Core can support both at the same time.

Is that simply a choice that Bitcoin Core made or is there something unique about Bitcoin Core in this case since it's a full-node wallet?

Comment: Do you mean having one key be multiple address types, or the wallet only gives out addresses of a single type? Regardless, Core being a full node is unrelated.

Comment: By "key" do you mean "seed"? Yes, I think I mean that Bitcoin Core is able to give different types of addresses per seed while other wallets can't.

Comment: It's not true, there are some mobile wallets like Samourai that support P2PKH, P2SH and segwit addresses derived from the seed.